# Using the return value of a function if it satisfies a condition without using an extra variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value

Assuming a function `some_function(x)` that returns an integer, I'm currently doing the following:

```
def another_function():
    # stuff...
    result = some_function(x)
    if result != 0:
        return result
    # else: more stuff (unrelated to result)...
```

What I want is to find the best way to write

```
if some_function(x) != 0:
    return some_function(x)
```

without of course calling `some_function(x)` twice.

Is there any more "clever" idiomatic way to write that in Python 3, without using `result`?

Comment: Why be clever? What you have is nice, clear and does the job. We tend to be too clever for our own good sometimes :-)

Comment: The clever idiomatic way is just what you already have. Look no further...

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I agree :>

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define an exception to raise when the function gives 0 as result. If that is the case, catch the error and do something else.

```
class ZeroResult(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        raise AttributeError

def some_function(x):
    #...
    if result==0:
        raise ZeroResult
    else:
        return result

def another_function():
    # stuff
    try:
        return some_function(x)
    except ZeroResult:
        # more stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo my comment in this answer and suggest that what you are currently doing is the best approach.

Dimgolds answer, if you went ahead and implemented a C.M, pretty much boils down to doing the same thing. FLabs approach uses an exception which, if the case is not exceptional, introduces unwanted overhead.

What you are doing is simple, explicit and completely understandable; things that are idiomatic in Python. Keep doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're addressing the result in few places, you'll have to either run it twice or save into a variable.

Another option (which is similar to using `result` ) is by using ''with'' statement and continue the `else` part:

```
with some_function(x) as result:
    if result: return result
```

This syntax won't keep result variable later on.

Comment: Functions are not automagically turned into context managers by trying to use them as such...  And FWIW variables defined by a contextmanager (here it would be `result`) DO outlive the `with` block, so it WOULD still 'keep result variable later on.'

Answer (score 0):

```
def mem(f, *args, **kwargs):
    r = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return r

def foo():
    print("hi, i'm here once")
    return 1

def bar(a,b):
    print("also once")
    return a+b

somefunc_with_foo = mem(foo)
print(somefunc_with_foo)
print(somefunc_with_foo)
somefunc_with_bar_2_3 = mem(bar,2,3)
print(somefunc_with_bar_2_3)
print(somefunc_with_bar_2_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the extra cuteness is worth it, but if you wanted to you could do with 2 functions.

```
return some_function(x) or my_other_stuff_that_gets_run_if_zero(x, y, z)
```

The boolean shortcut will return result right away on `some_function(x)` truthy and call (and return results for) another function if not.